# Displaying dot and dot dot paths in QListView - QT

Tags: qt

How to display folders and files in QListView but also, how to include dot and dot dot paths. I can simply display files and folders using QFileSystemModel, but dot dot is not being displayed.
Thanks for any hjalp.

Answer (score 2):

Look at [`QFileSystemModel::setFilter`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfilesystemmodel.html#setFilter)